# Make a Radio Button Selected by PHP Session

Tags: php, radio-button, session-variables

On the product page we have a code like this:

```
<select name="paymentmethod1" id="paymentmethod1">
<option value="MoneyPak">MoneyPak</option>
</select>


<select name="paymentmethod2" id="paymentmethod2">
<option value="MoneyPak">MoneyPak</option>
</select>
```

etc.

Through Session it writes to the order checkout form header as text such as MoneyPak or Credit Card through the code:

```
<?php echo($_SESSION["paymentmethod".$counter]); ?>
```

Now what I am trying to do here is get the user selection of Credit Card or MoneyPak radio button from the product page to automatically trigger the corresponding radio button to be checked:

```
<input name="1" type="radio" class="radio2" id="creditcard" style="padding-left:0px" 
onclick="showhide('creditcardxx', 'block'); showhide('m-p-kx', 'none'); 
showhide('splitx', 'none'); showhide('charge', 'block'); showhide('option3m', 'none'); 
showhide('option3', 'none'); showhide('option2', 'block')" value="creditcard"/>
```

I was thinking it could be something like this maybe but I can't get it to work:

```
<input name="1" <?php if (echo($_SESSION["paymentmethod".$counter])=='MoneyPak') {
echo checked="checked" ;} ?> type="radio" class="radio" id="MoneyPak" 
onclick="showhide('m-p-kx', 'block'); showhide('splitx', 'none'); 
showhide('creditcardxx', 'none'); showhide('paypalx', 'none'); showhide('charge', 
'none'); showhide('option3', 'none'); showhide('option3m', 'none'); showhide('option2', 
'none');" value="MoneyPak">
```

I also don't know if I should have else in both radio buttons or not.

Comment: I'm guessing there is an error in the rendered HTML. I would get a copy of the HTML source and drop in a HTML validator like: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Can someone please help?